# Websocket (ws4py in Python 3.5) not working in Docker container

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, docker, cherrypy, ws4py

I have a simple web application that uses CherryPy for a RESTful backend and ws4py for websockets.

```
1) Javascript client sends a POST to Python backend
2) Python replies with a unique id
3) Javascript connects to the websocket and sends the unique id
4) Python associates the websocket client connection to the unique id
```

Python websocket code:

```
class WebSocketHandler(WebSocket):
def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    WebSocket.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
    print('Connected to websocket server!')
    SUBSCRIBERS.add(self)

def received_message(self, message):
    print('Websocket identified itself?')
    SUBSCRIBERS_WITH_ID[message.data] = self
```

Python CherryPy code:

```
cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': 0.0.0.0,
                        'server.socket_port': 8080})

cherrypy.tools.CORS = cherrypy.Tool('before_handler', CORS)

WebSocketPlugin(cherrypy.engine).subscribe()
cherrypy.tools.websocket = WebSocketTool()

cherrypy.tree.mount(
    DummyAPI(), '/api/dummy', config={
        '/': {
            'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
            'tools.CORS.on': True
        }
    }
)

cherrypy.tree.mount(
    WebSocketAPI(), '/ws', config={
        '/': {
            'tools.websocket.on': True,
            'tools.websocket.handler_cls': WebSocketHandler
        }
    }
)

cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

Javascript code:

POST to API:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onload = function (e) {
    console.log('Response code: ' + req.responseText);
    result_id = req.responseText;
    websocketConnect();
};
req.open('POST', api_url);
req.send();
```

Websocket section:

```
function websocketConnect() {
websocket = new WebSocket(websocket_url);
websocket.onopen = function (evt) { 
      console.log("Connected to WebSocket server.");
      websocket.send(result_id)};
```

This works fine on my machine and deployed on Amazon EC2. However, when I try to deploy it in a Docker container, the websockets don't work.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python
MAINTAINER xxx

RUN pip3.5 install cherrypy ws4py
RUN mkdir /var/www

COPY python /var/www/python

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/python3.5", "/var/www/python/simplews.py"]
```

Output when I run from Docker:

```
sudo docker run  -v /tmp/dockertmp/:/tmp/ -p 8080:8080 -i 563a51d13f59
[23/Oct/2015:10:09:00] ENGINE Bus STARTING
[23/Oct/2015:10:09:00] ENGINE Starting WebSocket processing
[23/Oct/2015:10:09:00] ENGINE Started monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
[23/Oct/2015:10:09:00] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
[23/Oct/2015:10:09:01] ENGINE Serving on http://0.0.0.0:8080
[23/Oct/2015:10:09:01] ENGINE Bus STARTED
172.17.42.1 - - [23/Oct/2015:10:09:08] "POST ..."
Connected to websocket server!
```

It never reaches the stage where the Javascript file is able to send data through the websocket. Chrome debug shows the WS state as "Pending".

**However**, when I exit the CherryPy application in Docker, the websocket message comes through:

```
enter code here
sudo docker run  -v /tmp/dockertmp/:/tmp/ -p 8080:8080 -i 563a51d13f59
[23/Oct/2015:10:15:30] ENGINE Bus STARTING
[23/Oct/2015:10:15:30] ENGINE Starting WebSocket processing
[23/Oct/2015:10:15:30] ENGINE Started monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
[23/Oct/2015:10:15:30] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
[23/Oct/2015:10:15:30] ENGINE Serving on http://0.0.0.0:8080
[23/Oct/2015:10:15:30] ENGINE Bus STARTED
172.17.42.1 - - [23/Oct/2015:10:15:33] "POST ..."
Connected to websocket server!
^C[23/Oct/2015:10:15:35] ENGINE Keyboard Interrupt: shutting down bus
[23/Oct/2015:10:15:35] ENGINE Bus STOPPING
[23/Oct/2015:10:15:40] ENGINE HTTP Server     cherrypy._cpwsgi_server.CPWSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 8080)) shut down
[23/Oct/2015:10:15:40] ENGINE Stopped thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
[23/Oct/2015:10:15:40] ENGINE Terminating WebSocket processing
[23/Oct/2015:10:15:40] ENGINE Stopped thread 'Autoreloader'.
[23/Oct/2015:10:15:40] ENGINE Bus STOPPED
[23/Oct/2015:10:15:40] ENGINE Bus EXITING
[23/Oct/2015:10:15:40] ENGINE Bus EXITED
[23/Oct/2015:10:15:40] ENGINE Waiting for child threads to terminate...
Websocket identified itself?
```

Output when I run it without Docker:

```
python3.5 python/simplews.py 
[23/Oct/2015:06:09:45] ENGINE Bus STARTING
[23/Oct/2015:06:09:45] ENGINE Starting WebSocket processing
[23/Oct/2015:06:09:45] ENGINE Started monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
[23/Oct/2015:06:09:45] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
[23/Oct/2015:06:09:45] ENGINE Serving on http://0.0.0.0:8080
[23/Oct/2015:06:09:45] ENGINE Bus STARTED
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Oct/2015:06:09:48] "POST ..."
Connected to websocket server!
Websocket identified itself?
```

In the non-Docker case the websocket identifies itself immediately. I can't figure this out. Is the websocket receiver thread stuck somehow in Docker?

The suspicious part from the Docker logs is when the application exits, the websocket received message finally arrives:

```
[23/Oct/2015:10:15:40] ENGINE Waiting for child threads to terminate...
Websocket identified itself?
```

Comment: Have you tried running `strace -p [YOUR_SERVER_PID]` to see if you can see what it's stuck on?

Comment: Just ran it - turns out, the multiprocessing module was making the entire application stick somehow. When my app services the POST request, it launches a process with pool.starmap_async to generate the unique id. Maybe Docker + multiprocessing is no good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the Python multiprocessing module with threading.Thread fixed the problem. I was using multiprocessing in the POST method handler.

Here's the commit with the fix on the actual project:

https://github.com/sevagh/youtube-audio-dl/commit/9e23ae174f8791206b934608a1d4d702b411d18e